# How to configure FCM Push Notification in OpenFire

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp, openfire

I have added [PushNotification](https://github.com/igniterealtime/openfire-pushnotification-plugin/blob/master/README.md) plugin to my OpenFire server. But I have no clue on configuring FCM (or any other push notification system) using this.

The official [readme](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/0.8.0/pushnotification/readme.html) does not have much details.

Any help on where I can do the configuration will be appreciated.

Comment: As per PushNotification plugin, there is no integration with FCM. The plugin is just implementation of XEP-0357.
Do you have FCM integration on your own server side?

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal Yes I have. How can I integrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PushNotification](https://github.com/igniterealtime/openfire-pushnotification-plugin) plugin doesn't have direct integration with FCM as the plugin provides implementation of [XEP-0357](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0357.html).

If you have your own server side integration with FCM then by using CallbackOnOffline plugin, you can get http call from Openfire whenever there is an offline message in 1-1 chat.
Plugin configuration details are mentioned in it's [README](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/1.2.1/callbackOnOffline/readme.html) file.